# gojs addNodeData function doesn't add node to diagram

Tags: gojs

my code:

```
 diagram.nodeTemplate = this.getNodeTemplate();
 // ...
 let node1 =this.from;
 node1.key = id + "_0";
 node1.side = "left";
 node1.group = id;
 let node2 = this.to;
 node2.key = id + "_1";
 node2.side = "right";
 node2.group = id;
 diagram.startTransaction("new group");
 let groupNode = { key: id, isGroup: true, details: this };
 diagram.model.addNodeData(groupNode);
 diagram.commitTransaction("new group");
 diagram.startTransaction("new data");
 diagram.model.addNodeData(node1);
 diagram.model.addNodeData(node2);
 diagram.model.addLinkData({ from: node1.key, to: node2.key, fromPort: this.from.port.InvPortName, toPort: this.to.port.InvPortName, operation: this.operation });
diagram.commitTransaction("new data");
```

node2 added to the diagram. 
node1 is added to diagram.model.nodeDataArray, but not shown in the diagram, and getNodeTemplate function doesn't execute.

Comment: What `addNodeDataFunction` or `getNodeTemplate` functions are you talking about?  These do not exist as part of the GoJS API -- https://gojs.net/api

Comment: addNodeData is function of gojs.

Comment: The title of this topic refers to `addNodeDataFunction`. Regarding the `getNodeTemplate` function, I have node idea why your code that calls that function is not called.